# Best way to get a single value from request returning xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, performance

I have an Android app, and would like to get a specific value from an xml result set, that I am getting from a request to an api. I will be making multiple requests, and this is the only request that returns xml.

Here is the xml result:

https://mcxnow.com/orders?cur=WDC

How would I get the value of 'Doc > History > O[0] > p' as a string as efficiently as possible in Java for Android?

I've looked at Sax XML parser but that seems like overkill. Is there anything really lightweight I should use? What should I use, and how would I go about getting only the 1 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked at Sax XML parser but that seems like overkill. Is there anything really lightweight I should use? What should I use, and how would I go about getting only the 1 value?

I was going to recommend that you use a SAX parser!

---

The problem is that the only thing that is significantly more "light-weight" in performance terms is pattern matching; i.e. basically ignoring the XML grammar / syntax, and using regexes or equivalent to fish out the data that you want.

The problem with using pattern matching instead of proper XML parsing is that your code is liable to be fragile:

- It is liable to break in an unpredictable / undetectable fashion if the implied XML schema changes.
- It is liable to break in an unpredictable / undetectable fashion by variations in the way that the XML is formatted; e.g. non-significant white-space, attributes in an unexpected order, and so on.
- It is liable to break in an unpredictable / undetectable fashion if values are encoded in legal but unexpected ways.

And if you design your regexes to cope with these things, they get more complicated and the pattern matching performance drops.